# Charge unspecified battery pack through 2.5mm DC output cable

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, dc, charging

I recently bought a new bike/cycle that came with a BBB Highpower 2.0 torch/lamp. The lamp is attached to a battery pack with no specifications on the outside through a 2.5mm DC connection cable.

I lost the charger on my way home. The lamp is out of production, the manufacturer told me to consult an electronics store.

How can I safely charge the battery pack? I know 2.5mm DC to USB connectors exist, but I'm guessing that's too easy? Can somebody give me some pointers? Thanks!

UPDATE: [this](https://cdn1-originals.webdamdb.com/13269_93887672?Policy=eyJTdGF0ZW1lbnQiOlt7IlJlc291cmNlIjoiaHR0cCo6Ly9jZG4xLW9yaWdpbmFscy53ZWJkYW1kYi5jb20vMTMyNjlfOTM4ODc2NzIiLCJDb25kaXRpb24iOnsiRGF0ZUxlc3NUaGFuIjp7IkFXUzpFcG9jaFRpbWUiOjIxNDc0MTQ0MDB9fX1dfQ__&Signature=U0nqZOMa0xpJZlLb9%7EwridtwPx6zundqpChe4Mgkblj9ORFMHqpIDMXjpVNplvkvgElVSn1ABJfRrgJqjFwFF1WAHQyZp25mXR7JuMVdydXQopNq5aMb0H-RhQImAtcQKY0PYHy080D57jNLkNcficxj2Kzh8vwCeuZxtLlUq8NvwQakQ8LZHNOY7UNMpkLb5s8ZQjnxbXZAsmUF8X%7EwomEcehB3VS8GBoikCpgZHVIp34Dk-IWS9br2ifmm7rTjudIRe%7EsoZOjFnsMSCVwfOtOUvqgaxAeoOE4J38SBiHuCfXJBcRzGzI2i%7Eq%7E92pJ-044nQHPAJU5H-UcyzzjqZQ__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAI2ASI2IOLRFF2RHA) seems to be the manual. Specifications for the battery are:

- Lithium Ion
- 2x18650, 2200mAh, 7.4 V charging voltage
- 1hr charging time
- 150 grams
- charger 110V-240V, AC 50-60Hz
- Output current: 700 mAh +/- 10%

[image]

Comment: Without knowing what's inside the battery pack, or the specifications of the charger, there is no way of telling how to charge the battery pack safely.

Comment: Open the battery pack and see what's inside. Which may ruin any waterproofing or seal of the case. Or find one on fleabay second hand?

Comment: I updated the question to inlude info from the apparent manual. Does that change things?

Comment: Not a great deal. People often use the term "charger" to describe something that is simply a power supply, with the actual charging control circuits being built into the device itself (e.g. pretty much all mobile phone chargers nowadays).

Comment: ...though in this case, the fact that there's a status LED on the charger would suggest that it really IS a charger and not just a supply.

Comment: There's also an LED on the supposed battery pack.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have either a BLS-65 or BLS-66.
According to the manual, [here](https://bbbcycling.com/en_en/manuals) you need a 7.4V DC charger that will supply at least 1000ma of current and have the correct connector.

> Specification:
> Prim. voltage: 100-240 V AC 50-60 Hz
> Charging voltage: 7.4V DC
> Output current: 1000 mAh ±10%
> Battery pack: 2x 18650, 2200 mAh

Comment: Thats... incomplete. This isn't just a standard constant voltage charger.

Comment: Hi, I took a look at the manuals you provided and I'm pretty sure it's the BLS-63 Highpower model 2011. I'll update the question/info according to this manual.